# Accept date as user input in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, unix-timestamp

I want to accept date as input in `dd-mm-yyyy` format as user input (via read) and then convert it as a date object in shell script. How can I achieve this.
I have had success with `yyyy-mm-dd` but somehow,it is not working for my use case.

This is my script:-

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter a date (dd-mm-yyyy): " user_date
if date=$(date -d "$user_date" +'+%d-%m-%Y'); then 
  # user date was ok
  echo $date
```

This is my input:-

```
./2.sh
Enter a date (dd-mm-yyyy): 11-1-2011
```

Error:

```
date: invalid date `11-1-2011'
```

Thanks

Comment: Why what is the error ?

Comment: This is `bash` script, not `python`

Comment: @ZdaR. I have updated my question with error message

Comment: @sirfz Yes gentleman. That's already mentioned in my question subject . Sorry for wrongly tagging it under python

Comment: AFAICS, you don't get to specify what the input format looks like.  I have a program `strptime` which is basically a cover for the function [`strptime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html) to parse date strings.  For example: `strptime -T '%d-%m-%Y' 11-1-2011` yields
`1294732800 = 11-1-2011`, and then using `date`, I can get: `date -d @1294732800` to produce
`Tue Jan 11 00:00:00 PST 2011` which is the correct time zone (US/Pacific, aka America/Los_Angeles).

Answer (score 1):

To compare two strings (there are no date objects, just the string output of the `date` command), you need to use either `[` or preferably a conditional statement `[[ ... ]]` .

```
if [[ $user_date = $(date -d "$user_date" +'+%d-%m-%Y') ]]; then
```

Of course, there's no guarantee that `date` can parse the string entered by the user as a date.